# Abrir archivo en python sin ruta local (ruta relativa)

Tags: python

Estoy intentando abrir un archivo, llamémoslo 'texto1.txt', mediante una ruta relativa. Alguien me puede decir como se haría. Gracias.

Comment: Para abrir un archivo en python utiliza el metodo `open(file, action)`. Para mas información te recomiendo revisar este tutorial: https://uniwebsidad.com/libros/python/capitulo-9/metodos-del-objeto-file

Answer (score -1):

Creo que si haces esto lo podrías abrir:

```
    import os

Ruta = 'C:/Prueba/'
Ruta2 = 'Carpeta1/texto1.txt'
Ruta3 = os.path.join(Ruta, Ruta2)
Ruta3 = os.path.abspath(Ruta3)
print(Ruta3)
```

Con esto añades las dos rutas

Comment: A parte de publicar el código, en tu respuesta deberías explicar por qué el código compartido resuelve el problema.